# laravel 5.4 controller middleware construct not working

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have some code :

AController

```
class AController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        echo 'outside - AController';
        echo '<br/>';

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            echo 'inside - AController';
            echo '<br/>';

            return $next($request);
        });

    }

    public function handle()
    {

        $B = new BController;
        if ( $B->check() ) {
            $controller = BController::class;
            $action = 'index';
        } else {
            $controller = BController::class;
            $action = 'nothing';
        }

        $container = app();
        $route = $container->make(Route::class);
        $controllerInstance = $container->make($controller);

        return (new ControllerDispatcher($container))->dispatch($route, $controllerInstance, $action);

    }

}
```

BController

```
class BController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        echo 'outside - BController';
        echo '<br/>';

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            echo 'inside - BController';
            echo '<br/>';

            return $next($request);
        });

    }

}
```

When BController is called from AController, in the browser show :

outside - AController

inside - AController

outside - BController

why middleware in BController when called from AController not showing like this?

outside - AController

inside - AController

outside - BController

inside - BController

Answer (score 0):

use Middleware in route instead  of using construct in controller.
here is the laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Comment: The middleware in __construct for the purpose set some variable global from $request and can be called from another function. So middleware in route is not what I'm looking for. I know we can use public function __construct(Request $request), but I want to use middleware in __construct to set some variable global and set middleware of some function